# Background image on UICollectionViewController

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to port a native iOS application over to Xamarin/MonoTouch. In my story board I had a UICollectionViewController which had a background UIImageView that was rendered first to show a background for the collection. When I open that in Xamarin Studio the image is gone and I now have a UICollectionReusableView but no image. I tried to add an image and only seem to be able to add it to this reusable view however it never shows up.

I tried in the view controller to manually add an image, it appears but then the cells are hidden. If I send the UIImageView to the back then the image becomes hidden, even though the collection view has a background color of Clear.

Here are my studio/sdk versions:

Xamarin Studio
Version 5.9.1 (build 3)
Runtime: Mono 4.0.0 ((detached/d136b79)
GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)

Apple Developer Tools
Xcode 6.3.2 (7718)
Build 6D2105

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 8.10.0.267

Comment: There *should* be no difference between your former native implementation and your Xamarin one. Did you try to use XCode instead of the Xamarin Studio Storyboard designer? I'm not sure it is doing things correctly, so personally I always prefer XCode over Xamarin Studio for that task.

Comment: Yes, I tried opening with XCode and then it shows the image that was originally there however Xamarin ignores it, it also won't generate an IBOutlet for it either. When I save and go back into Xamarin, the image is gone.